# Draw a map with gps markers and save this image to file

Tags: python, gps, openstreetmap

I have some GPS position recordings, which I want to draw into a map (e.g. OpenStreetMap) and save this as an image file.

I'm using python. I've found [osm-gps-map](http://nzjrs.github.com/osm-gps-map/) as a candidate library to do the visualization, but apparantly the [API](http://nzjrs.github.com/osm-gps-map/docs/reference/html/api-index-full.html) lacks some functionality to satisfy all of my needs. What I need is a library that does:

- draw stuff into a map (e.g. an OSM-based map), i.e. a list of GPS positions.
- automatically adjust view (scale/position) to fit in all drawn positions
- save this view to an image file

I seriously want to avoid being forced to manually make a screenshot from a widget or a browser window. And if possible I also want to avoid to implement the necessary projection functionality by myself (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6172355/1025391)). Does anyone know a library/toolchain that provides the desired functionality (if possible for use by Python)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to consider using [Basemap](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/) for matplotlib.  Here is a [blog post](http://stevendkay.wordpress.com/tag/basemap/) describing how to use this package with OSM.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples of how to draw custom GPS points on top of OSM background map using Matplotlib Basemap, Matplotlib or Cairo in GeoTiler project: https://github.com/wrobell/geotiler/tree/master/examples.