# How to draw a png-osm-map with coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, openstreetmap

I want to create a map with several given points in Python. For this I want to use [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) from matplotlib. It works well, but I don't know how to get a proper background map.

How can I import an [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) map? Or should I use a different mapping package? I just want to create a raster map and save it as png.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482335/draw-a-map-with-gps-markers-and-save-this-image-to-file/9485409#9485409

Comment: But the blog post linked there only describes a solution that forces me to combine two images (map and points) by photoshop/gimp, I need a full automated solution

Comment: teGuy... post your solution (with as much detail as possible) as an answer... then accept it. It's more than ok to answer your own questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 3):

**This not my solution; I have pasted it from the question because the asker doesn't have enough reputation to answer his own question.**

> I found a solution:
>
> Using `imshow` within Basemap includes an png into the plot as
>   background image. To obtain the right background image, I used the
>   [export feature of OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export?lat=38&lon=-95.8&zoom=4&layers=M) with boundaries taken from the Basemap
>   constructor:
>
> ```
> m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=7.4319, urcrnrlat=52.0632, urcrnrlon=7.848, llcrnrlat=51.8495,
>         resolution='h', projection='merc')
>
> im = plt.imread('background.png')
> m.imshow(im, interpolation='lanczos', origin='upper')
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I found some accessible basemap imagery from NASA GIBS tileserver.  You might be able to use the same method for other tileservers.

http://earthdata.nasa.gov/wiki/main/index.php/GIBS_Supported_Clients#Script-level_access_to_imagery

Thi Uses GDAL's gdal_translate in a python subshell:

```
import subprocess
import matplotlib.pyplot
import mpl_toolkits.basemap

l,u,r,d=(7.4319,52.0632,7.848,51.8495)

subprocess.call ('gdal_translate -of GTiff -outsize 400 400 -projwin {l} {u} {r} {d} TERRA.xml Background.tif'.format(l=l,u=u,r=r,d=d),shell=True )

im=matplotlib.pyplot.imread('Background.tif')

m = mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap(llcrnrlon=l, urcrnrlat=u, urcrnrlon=r, llcrnrlat=d,
    resolution='h', projection='merc')
m.imshow(im, interpolation='lanczos', origin='upper')

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

This needs the TERRA.xml file from the above link, though you can inline the XML as well.